# Bootstrap.js (3.1) collapse('hide') doesn't hide element if called too soon after collapse('show')

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code which calls the bootstrap 3.1 js method `collapse()` on a div with either 'show' or 'hide' as a parameter based on the value of the selected item in a select input element.

The problem I am having is that if the user changes selections too quickly via up/down arrows on the keyboard, she will momentarily pass over 'Corner, and the div will be shown, but when she continues on to another selection, the div will not be hidden, even though the end value of `$selectedText` does not equal 'Corner'.

I presume this is because `$col.collapse('hide')` is called before `$col.collapse('show')` has completed, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="cubicleConfigurationForm">
    <div class="row cubicleConfigurationForm_rowWorkSurfaceConfiguration">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><abbr title="Work Surface" class="initialism">WS</abbr> Depth</label>
                    <select name="cubicleConfigurationForm_cubicle1_ddlWorkSurfaceDepth" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0">Undefined</option>
                        <option value="24">D24</option>
                        <option value="30">D30</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><abbr title="Work Surface" class="initialism">WS</abbr> Configuration</label>
                    <select name="cubicleConfigurationForm_cubicle1_ddlWorkSurfaceConfig" class="form-control cubicleConfigurationForm_ddlWorkSurfaceConfig">
                        <option value="0">Undefined</option>
                        <option value="2">Corner</option>
                        <option value="1">L Shape</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 cubicleConfigurationForm_colCurvedCorner collapse in" style="height: auto;">
                <label>Curved Corner?</label>
                <br>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cubicleConfigurationForm_cubicle1_cbCurvedCornerRequested">
                        Curved Corner
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#cubicleConfigurationForm').on('change', '.cubicleConfigurationForm_ddlWorkSurfaceConfig', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $selectedText = $this.find(':selected').text();
    var $col = $this.parents('div.cubicleConfigurationForm_rowWorkSurfaceConfiguration').children('div.cubicleConfigurationForm_colCurvedCorner');

    if ($selectedText === 'Corner') {
        $col.collapse('show');
    }
    else {
        $col.collapse('hide');
        ClearFormFields($col);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Ly1qtzbp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the `select` till the animation is done so that the issue wont arise. I tried to check the `$col` after a quick change from `Corner` to  `L Shape` and found that the `$col` was having class `collapsing` which meant the previous transition was not complete.

JS

```
//disabling the select here
if ($selectedText === 'Corner') {
    $col.collapse('show');
    $('select').prop('disabled', 'disabled')

} else {
    $col.collapse('hide');
    $('select').prop('disabled', 'disabled')        
    ClearFormFields($col);
}


//enabling the select after the animation is done i.e on shown or hidden. #test is given for this demo
$('#test').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log("shown");
    $('select').prop('disabled', '')
})

$('#test').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log("hidden");
    $('select').prop('disabled', '')
})
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/Ly1qtzbp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to simply toggle the visibility of the div instead of using the collapse animation. Using the JQuery methods `hide()` and `show()` like shown below seems to perform well enough to get the job done.

```
    if ($selectedText === 'Corner') {
        $col.show();
    }
    else {
        $col.hide();
        ClearFormFields($col);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and if you use hide(), the collapse won't work until you show() it again.
To show/hide the element without "breaking" the collapse, you can add/remove "in" class to/from it

```
$col.addClass('in');
...
$col.removeClass('in');
```